# Installing a port with all of its dependecies

Tags: opencv, macports

I been trying to install a port with the command `sudo port install NAME_OF_PORT`

The issue I am having with this particular port (OpenCV) is that it keeps asking me for dependencies with an error like the following:

```
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: libunwind-headers 
llvm-3.1 llvm_select
```

Is there any way I can `sudo port install NAME_OF_PORT` with all of its dependencies with just one command?

Thanks a lot for your time, any tip much appreciated.

Comment: Usually all dependencies are automatically installed. Maybe an error occurred while installing some of them. Try installing those again by hand.

Comment: Thanks Vortexfive, I tried installing them by hand, but they itself have dependencies so it was getting forever

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888222/trouble-installing-libunwind-headers-via-macports . It is possible that you have a problem installing libunwind-headers (which is a dependency of llvm and opencv). If no errors occur for any of the dependencies, macports should automatically install them all.

Comment: Thanks I will try using sudo xcodebuild -license agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `sudo port -v selfupdate` and then rerun `sudo port install opencv`. If that's not helping try running `sudo port upgrade outdated` to upgrade outdated dependencies.

Also take a look at this guide I wrote: [Compile OpenCV (2.3.1+) for OS X Lion / Mountain Lion with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552839/compile-opencv-2-3-1-for-os-x-lion-mountain-lion-with-xcode/8559953#8559953)

Comment: Thanks a lot and thanks for the guide, I will be testing everything right now

Comment: @JordanBelf Don't forget to accept the answer, if it was helpful / solved your problem …

Comment: Yes yes, sorry about the delay. I am testing everything and OpenCV in taking me forever to get it right but I sure will once I get everything working

Comment: The answer to this question might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755274/downloading-macports-dependencies-without-installing